# Last floated box adding space?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a 3 column grid with 2 rows, where the second box on the first row is a double col, a featured section essentially.

However, the final box is adding additional space to itself, each single column box has a right margin apart from the final box, but as you can see from this quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMKdx/4/) there is additional space at the bottom right...

```
 .blocks > div{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.block{
width: 31.33%; 
height: 25%;   

 }

.block.one{
margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-right: 9px;

    background-color: green;
}
.block.two.feature{
    width: 66.2%;
margin-bottom: 9px;
    background-color: red;
}
.block.three{
background-color: blue;
margin-right: 9px;
}
.block.four{
background-color: purple;

 margin-right: 9px;
}
.block.five{
    margin-right:0; 
background-color: pink;
}
```

If i remove the margin, and just divide the boxes by 3 they sit flush in there, as soon as i add the margin it seems to effect the final box.

I don’t have a clue why and doesn’t make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `box-sizing` property to help control the block widths, it is better to use **padding** rather than **margin** for the gutters. As explained [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), box-sizing only incorporates the padding into the element width (not the margin).

Then, since you need the blocks to have a background color, the best way to handle this is to wrap each block in a container and apply padding to the containers. I realize that having those extra divs isn't ideal, but this really is the proper way and in a real layout you'll almost always have something inside there anyway. This also helps separate layout styles from module styles, as taught [here](http://smacss.com/).

To prevent the first and last blocks in each "row" from having space on the outside, we override the left/right padding using `alpha` and `omega` classes. This technique is pretty common; check out the source code for popular CSS grid frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Here's the most relevant code from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMKdx/10/). Happy to help if anything isn't clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/DMKdx/10/

```
.blocks{
    background-color: grey;
    width:80%;
    height:670px;
}

.block{
    width: 33.33333333333%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 4.5px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.block.alpha {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.block.omega {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.block.feature {
    width: 66.6666666666667%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for everyone else’s suggestions, i had no idea it was so ‘complex'